# Why does WinDbg 10.0.19041 x86 fail where WinDbg 6.12 succeeds?

Tags: c#, windbg

Started to go to the deeper end of the pool with exploring WinDbg (not Preview).
Managed to get two installations side-by-side - versions 6.12 (stand-alonish from stackoverflow links to microsoft servers) and 10.0.19041 (from Windows SDK).

Debugging a simple Hello-World .Net Framework 4.7.2 console application (AnyCPU 32bit preferred on 64bit Windows 7) works as expected in Windbg x86 6.12, but not on the new one.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19041.685 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: D:\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00bf0000 00bf8000   ConsoleApplication2.exe
Unable to get program counter
WaitForEvent failed
Unable to get program counter
eax=00bf27de ebx=fffde000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=779f01c4 esp=0028fd5c ebp=00000000 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
0023:01c4 ??              ???
```

Output from 6.12

```
CommandLine: D:\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe
Symbol search path is: srv*C:\Symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ModLoad: 00bf0000 00bf8000   ConsoleApplication2.exe
ModLoad: 779e0000 77b60000   ntdll.dll
ModLoad: 64720000 6476a000   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\MSCOREE.DLL
ModLoad: 77210000 77320000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.dll
ModLoad: 76f80000 76fc7000   C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
(1fb8.20b0): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=705a0000 edx=0026dd78 esi=fffffffe edi=00000000
eip=77a80ed4 esp=0019f7b4 ebp=0019f7e0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x2c:
77a80ed4 cc              int     3
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 reached end of life on January 14, 2020, while the Windows 10 SDK 10.0.19041 was released after that, so you can assume that anything from that SDK release is not tested any more on Windows 7, and any issue like the one you observed is by design.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/policies/fixed)

Comment: @blabb Windows 10 is far from "the latest and greatest", while Windows 8.1 is still supported by Microsoft. It is just Windows 7 (released more than a decade ago) that went out of support a year ago. So if you consider that a conspiracy, you are overreactive.

Comment: Well, the 64bit version works as expected. Also, they have made the Preview version very officially NOT support Windows 7. So, I doubt that it is that. I think I read something since I posted talking about WinDbgs viewing the application as 16 bit (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4f366abd-7ec9-4bd0-b537-7eee6b438835/open-executable-in-windbg?forum=windbg)

Comment: @blabb "why a robust debugger should loose its credibility by not being able to debug simple console app"? What credibility? Probably you never developed/maintained a product for such a series of operating systems yourself. By ending support of a very old platform, there is not only no need to test against it, but also a chance to remove all the hacks around it. If you check other vendors you see similar policies and often shorter product lifecycles.

Comment: @LexLi Turns out you are right. After installing Windows 10 SDK, version 1903 (10.0.18362.1) - last one before EOL for Windows 7 - everything works as expected.